# Force height of div to fill browser while keeping sticky footer in place

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to extend the height of my content div to fill the browser while also implementing a sticky footer.

I have implemented the sticky footer using this method ->
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

I can't seem to keep the footer in place while also forcing the content div to fill the height.

I've searched for a while on how to do this but haven't come up with anything useful. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code -> https://jsfiddle.net/rpunumr6/

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #576772;
}
.page-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
    height: 60px;
}
.site-footer {
    background-color: #7C8B9E;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
}
header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #728579;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1200px;
}
.site-body {
    background-color: #DCE0D8;
    width: 880px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
    background-color: #7C8B9E;
    height: 60px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<title>Page Title</title>
<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <header>
            <nav></nav>
        </header>
        <div class="site-body">
             <h1>Title</h1>

            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the css `calc` function to calculate the `height` of your `.site-body` div.

Knowing the `height` of the `header` plus the `height` of the `footer` and finally the `padding` of the `.site-body`, calc will let you subtract the pixel value from a percentage value.

## [**CSS calc()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

> The calc() CSS function can be used anywhere a length, frequency, angle, time, number, or integer is required. With calc(), you can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

[**can i use calc ?**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Here is an example.

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #576772;
}
.page-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 60px;
}
.site-footer {
  background-color: #7C8B9E;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #728579;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}
section {
}
.site-body {
  background-color: #DCE0D8;
  width: 880px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  height: calc(100% - 180px);
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  background-color: #7C8B9E;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<title>Page Title</title>
<body>
  <div class="page-wrap">
    <header>
      <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <div class="site-body">
      <h1>Title</h1>

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="site-footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully. You have saved me much time and aggravation.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that the only way to solve it (instead of mimicking it, by changing the body background color to be the same as content background color) was to use java script.  Below the snippet I use.

```
var height_diff = $( window ).height() - $( 'body' ).height();
 if ( height_diff > 0 ) {
     $( '.site-body' ).css( 'padding-bottom', height_diff );  }
```

This checks for the difference in height between the window and your body, then adds padding to the bottom of the content to fill the screen.

I use this snippet instead of pure css, because my header and footer height is dynamic and not fixed.

Comment: I took this sample out of my site, but I'll see if I can get it to work in the fiddle.  Ill try when  I get home tonight.